# Template explicit instantiation (definition and declaration) in gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, explicit-instantiation

Suppose there is a code like this:

```
template <typename T>
CLASS_KEY1 X{};

PREFIX template CLASS_KEY2 X<int>;
```

where `CLASS_KEY1`, `CLASS_KEY2` and `PREFIX` are macros. `CLASS_KEY1` and `CLASS_KEY2` may be expanded to `class`, `struct` or `union` keywords. `PREFIX` may be expanded to empty set of characters or `extern` keyword.

Here is the table which shows when such code compiles (`Yes` - compiles, `No` - does not compile) for all combinations of macros values (compiler gcc-4.8.1, option `-std=c++11`):

```
PREFIX                                        extern  extern  extern
CLASS_KEY1\CLASS_KEY2 class   struct  union   class   struct  union
class                 Yes     Yes?    No      Yes     Yes?    No
struct                Yes?    Yes     No      Yes?    Yes     No
union                 No      No      Yes     No      No      Yes
```

Is it a bug in gcc or standard requirement (strange cases are labeled with question marks)? What about other compilers?

Comment: Appart from the encapsulation policy, there is no difference between `struct` and `class`. I bet that the retained policy is the one anounced where the class is defined.

Comment: However, clang++ produces a warning when you try to do so: `warning: class template 'X' was previously declared as a struct template`. Both compilers apply the encapsulation policy annoucned where the class is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 7.1.6.3 (Elaborated type specifiers) of the C++11 standard says :

> The *class-key* or `enum` keyword present in the *elaborated-type-specifier* shall agree in kind with the declaration to which the name in the *elaborated-type-specifier* refers. This rule also applies to the form of *elaborated-type-specifier* that declares a *class-name* or `friend` class since it can be construed as referring to the definition of the class. Thus, in any *elaborated-type-specifier*, the `enum` keyword shall be used to refer to an enumeration (7.2), the `union` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a `union` (Clause 9), and either the `class` or `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a `class` (Clause 9) declared using the `class` or `struct` *class-key*.

So, the behavior you're seeing is allowed.